# Declare Typescript global variable as "module" type

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I have the React type definition file (that is declared using an external module).  In my source files, I usually do:

```
import * as R from "react"
```

and can then happily use `R.createElement(...` etc in a strongly typed fashion.

What I want is to not have to import `R` in every file, and instead have it as a global declaration (yes, I'm willing to polute the global namespace with a few variables).  I've tried:

```
import * as React from "react";
declare var R : React;
```

This doesn't work though, I get `"Cannot find name 'React'"`.  Is there another way to export the entire module as global?

---

*Edit 1* -
I should have made clearer: I'm interested in how to export a global *type definition* in a `.d.ts` file.  So assume I've attached `R` to `window` already.  Now I need typescript to know that `R` is of type `React module`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> instead have it as a global

There are two sides to this: `global type declaration` for typescript and `global variable availability` for JavaScript consumption.

## Global Type Declaration

A `.d.ts` or a declaration only contributes to the *global* name declaration space if there is no root level *import* or *export* in the file. So have a file `globalreact.d.ts` which will be an *edited* version of https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts of the form `declare module R` (instead of `declare module "react"`).

## Global Variable Export

You need to put it on `window` in case of the browser. So do the following in a file `makeReactGlobal.ts`:

```
var R = require('react'); 
(<any>window).R = R
```

And then in your application `main` have this file a dependency to ensure that it executes before any of your other code.

Comment: Thanks for all the details.  I'm interested in the Global Type Declaration part, and was really hoping not to have to hack the react.d.ts file.  Seeing as typescript would understand `import * as R from 'react';  var _r = R;` I was really wanting a way to just put that in a `.d.ts` file.

Comment: Not technically possible AFAIK considering how the definition is written atm.

Comment: I posted this to the Typescript team -- looks like it's not possible: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3180#issuecomment-102523512

Comment: Marking as answer, even though there is no answer :(

Answer (score 1):

The `declare` keyword does not declare a variable in the global scope. This keyword is used for cases in which there will be a variable in the global scope and you want to use it in a TypeScript without getting compilation errors.

You can declare a global variable with:

```
import * as R from "react";
window.R = R;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- this is how you'd expose it on the javascript side.  I'm trying to expose the typing itself (see @basarat answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Like @basarat said, it doesn't look like it's possible.  @ahejlsberg himself weighed in on the issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3180#issuecomment-102523512.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close (place this in a `.d.ts` file somewhere tsc will find it):

```
import * as React from "react";

declare global {
  const R: typeof React;
}
```

(Note the added "typeof". Haven't tested with React, but it works for me with Vue.)