# Import jquery and bootstrap in typescript commonjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typescript

i'm using browserify to import some nodejs modules. All working fine using this sintax:

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require('angular');
require('ngRoute');
require('firebase');
require('angularfire');
```

Now i'm trying to convert that in typescript (using version 1.8) but i can't figure how to do it. I'm using tsify plugin from browserify

i've tried some sintax like

```
import * as jquery from "jquery";
import * as jQuery from "jquery";
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

or

```
declare var jQuery;
declare var $;
import * as jquery from "jquery";
$ = jQuery =jquery;
```

but it's not working!

Answer (score 11):

To have 'jQuery' available globally in the browser you need to attach it to the windows object.

This works for me:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
(<any>window).jQuery = $

import "bootstrap";
```

See this answer: [Declare Typescript global variable as "module" type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219843/declare-typescript-global-variable-as-module-type)

Answer (score 1):

at the start of your file you have to tell typescript it should know the typescript definitions of nodejs, jquery and so on.

```
/// <reference path="DEFINITION-FILE.d.ts" />
```

require is not known before the d.ts file nodejs isn't referenced
$ or jquery is not known befor the d.ts file for jquery is not referenced ...

you can find a a large package of typescript definitions on Definitly Typed

http://definitelytyped.org/

i hope this is helpfull

Comment: The project compile successfully so it can't be a definitions problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

Make sure you have jQuery installed:

```
typings install jquery --save
```

Answer (score 0):

import $ from "jquery"; is what works here.