# TypeScript $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, typescript-typings

The following error is logged in the console when I try to attach a tooltip.

> Uncaught TypeError: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

My compiler shows me all the tooltip options via intellisense so it seems to be picking up the bootstrap module via the type definition file.

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";

$(function () {
    // jquery works
    $("#btnOnboardingFilesUpload")
        .click(function () { alert('upload files'); })
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
        .attr('title', 'You haven\'t selected any files.')
        .attr('data-placement', 'top');

    // bootstrap doesn't? Uncaught TypeError: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    $("#btnOnboardingFilesUpload").tooltip();
});
```

When I attempt to log bootstrap via `console.log(bootstrap);` the object is empty:

```
{}
```

Any idea why bootstrap wouldn't be loaded?

I have the following dependencies in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5"
  },
```

Comment: I can't wrap my head around why this question was downvoted.  Can someone explain the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was struggling with the same thing, and I think the solution is just to replace your import with `import "bootstrap";`

Since everything you want from Bootstrap is just an extension of jQuery, that seems to be the secret sauce.  For reference, this solution was derived from another answer on SO: [Import jquery and bootstrap in typescript commonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076612/import-jquery-and-bootstrap-in-typescript-commonjs)

Example:

```
import "jquery";
import "bootstrap";

export class Grid {
    // additional properties here...

    constructor(options?:Partial<Grid>) {
        $.extend(this, options); // allow for assigning values to properties via the constructor
    }
    Initialize() {
        var _this = this;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).on('load', function () {
                $(_this.FileUploadButton)
                    .click(function () { _this.UploadFiles($(this)); })
                    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                    .attr('title', 'You haven\'t selected any files.')
                    .attr('data-placement', 'top')
                    .tooltip();
    // etc...
```

Comment: You are correct.  That is what worked for me, also.  I've edited your answer to include code from my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Importing bootstrap like in the above answers caused my problems.

What I did in order to fix it is the below:

1. In ***package.json***, I've added `"@types/jquery": "^3.5.14"` & `"@types/bootstrap": "5.1.9"` to the `devDependencies` field.
2. In ***tsconfig.json***, I've added `"jquery"` & `"bootstrap"` to `compilerOptions.types` list, so it looks something like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules/@types",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "node",
      "bootstrap"
    ],
```

Then execute `npm i` and `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, though I am not sure why, bootstrap works correctly when I wrap it in `(function($) { })(jQuery);` IIFE.

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";

class EditableGrid {
    $DepartmentsSelectlist: any = $('.select-onboarding-department');
    $ErrorsAlertDiv: any = $('.alert-onboarding-errors');
    $UploadFilesInput: any = $("#OnboardingFilesInput");
    $GridTable: any = $('#onboardingFilesGrid');
    Initialize(): void {
        var _this = this;
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(window).on('load', function () {
                    console.log(bootstrap);
                    // jquery works
                    $("#btnOnboardingFilesUpload")
                        .click(function () { _this.UploadFiles($(this)); })
                        .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                        .attr('title', 'You haven\'t selected any files.')
                        .attr('data-placement', 'top');

                    // bootstrap works now!
                    $("#btnOnboardingFilesUpload").tooltip();
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    }
    UploadFiles(btnUpload) {
        alert('upload files');
    }
}

var onboardingGrid = new EditableGrid();
onboardingGrid.Initialize();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also solve this by using the rubygems jquery-ui-rails and jquery-ui-themes My application.js has require("bootstrap") and import("bootstrap") but I was having the same problem TypeError: $(…).tooltip is not a function I solved by using the gems