# How can I declare a global variable in TypeScript and use it across in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a **main.ts** file, I want to declare a variable over there and use it across all the **Vue** files.

I have a **sfc.d.ts** with this content:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
   import Vue from 'vue'
   export default Vue
}

declare var foo: any;
```

I assigned a value to `foo = "1234"` in **main.ts**.
How can I use this `foo` variable in all the Vue files? 
Or is there any other way, to create global variable and use it across?

Comment: `(window as any).foo = "1234";` or `(<any> window).foo = "1234";`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare Typescript global variable as "module" type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219843/declare-typescript-global-variable-as-module-type)

Comment: There may be few more global variable, is it correct to store all in window object?

Comment: That is the definition of a global variable in the browser - all of them exist as properties on the window object. If you need you're almost certainly doing something wrong, though.

Comment: yeah correct. i agree. is this the only way or is there any other way?

Comment: Of course, you can use ```localstorage```or ```vuex store``` to share a variable across of Components.

Answer (score 0):

```js
declare global {
    const foo: string;
}
```

but I must say, this is an anti-pattern and bad practice (for production)

Comment: it's not if your use case requires it. this is ok as long as u know what you are doing.

Comment: the question is not "if you know what you are doing", it is "if you know what others are doing and if they know what you are doing". JavaScript global scope pollution is one of the most common and know anti-pattern. e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-global-namespace-pollution-in-javascript